# Open bootstrap table row in new table with possible field editor

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-table

I'm using [bootstrap table library](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/) in my app that to render table with massive data and I need to open row in additional editable table. I found a lot of info in internet how to open row in model and put edited code to my app that to display row info inside div but cannot set it that to open it in editable table. I provide the [plunker example](https://plnkr.co/edit/MCyxfOM1ctuDVZllkw04?p=preview).

**Updated** Cause I didn't get any work solution, I've tried to fix it by myself, so I know the solution isn't so good but for now it works for me. The question is still asking, how to edit field of new rendered table?

This is function of my solution:

```
   $(function () {
    var $result = $('#form');

$('#table').on('click-row.bs.table', function (e, row, $element) {

    $('.success').removeClass('success');
    $($element).addClass('success');

    //alert('Selected name: ' + getSelectedRow().text);

    function getSelectedRow() {
        var index = $('#table').find('tr.success').data('index');
        return $('#table').bootstrapTable('getData')[index];
    }

    $result.html(

        '<table border="0" align="left" style="padding: 10px; margin: 10px; font-size: 14px; color: #0f0f0f">' + '<h3>'+
        '<tr  align="left" style="padding: 10px; margin: 10px;">' + '<td style="font-weight: bold;">Name</td>' + '<td>&nbsp;</td>' + '<td>' + getSelectedRow().name + '</td>' + '</tr>' +
        '<tr align="left" style="padding: 10px; margin: 10px;">' + '<td style="font-weight: bold;">Structure</td>'  + '<td>&nbsp;</td>' +  '<td>' + getSelectedRow().stargazers_count + '</td>'+ '</tr>'+
        '<tr align="left" style="padding: 10px; margin: 10px;"> '+ '<td style="font-weight: bold;">Class</td>' + '<td>&nbsp;</td>' +  '<td>' + getSelectedRow().forks_count + '</td>'+ '</tr>'+
        '<tr align="left" style="padding: 10px; margin: 10px;"> '+ '<td style="font-weight: bold;">Description</td>' + '<td>&nbsp;</td>' +  '<td>' + getSelectedRow().description + '</td>'+ '</tr>'+
        '</h3>' + '</table>'
        );
    })
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use modals of boostrap, will open a modal. Check the documentation on http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#via-javascript, just add the html, css and js references and call this code:

$('#table').on('click-row.bs.table', function (e, row, $element){           $('#myModal').modal('show') //Will be call the modal when you click a row 
})

And you can pass all the information to the modal via javascript. Hope you understand me. :)

Comment: I don't need to open model (I know how it works), I need to set up form for row of table. When you click on row it should render to you form under table which you can edit.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I get what you need but i add this code on the

html:

```
<div id="form">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Title1" id="titleForm1"></input>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Title2" id="titleForm2"></input>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Title3" id="titleForm3"></input>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Title4" id="titleForm4"></input>
</div>
```

js:

```
$('#table').on('click-row.bs.table', function (e, row, $element) {
    /*$result.html(
        '<pre>' +
        JSON.stringify(row, null, 1).replace(/,|}|{/g, " ")
            //JSON.stringify(row).replace(/,/g, "<br/>")
        + '</pre>'
    );*/
    $('#titleForm1').val(row.name);
    $('#titleForm2').val(row.stargazers_count);
    $('#titleForm3').val(row.forks_count);
    $('#titleForm4').val(row.description);
    console.log(row);
})
```

Hope it helps you.